# How to prove $\mathscr{T}_Y $ is a topology on $Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathscr{T})$ be a topological space. Define $Y\subseteq X$ and $\mathscr{T}_Y \subseteq P(Y)$.

**Prop:** $\mathscr{T}_{Y}$ is a topology on $Y$.

We wish to show that $\mathscr{T}_{Y}$ contains empty set and $Y$ itself, and finitely many intersections/unions of open sets is in $\mathscr{T}_{Y}$.

Comment: define $\mathcal{T}_Y$. We can guess it, but you should state a *complete* problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Suppose that $X=\mathbb R$, the $\mathscr T$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, that $Y=[-1,1]$ and that $\mathscr T_Y=\left\{\left\{0\right\}\right\}$. Then $Y\subseteq X$ and $\mathscr T_Y\subseteq\mathcal P(Y)$, but $\mathscr T_Y$ is *not* a topology.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is defined in the usual way as $$\mathcal{T}_Y = \{O \cap Y: O \in \mathcal{T}\}$$

1. $Y = X \cap Y$ and $X \in \mathcal{T}$.
2. $\emptyset = \emptyset \cap Y$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.
3. If $O_1, O_2, \ldots, O_n \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ then for each $i$, $O_i = O'_i \cap Y$ for $O'_i \in \mathcal{T}$. It follows that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n O'_i \in \mathcal{T}$ and so $\bigcap_{i=1}^n O_i = Y \cap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n O'_i) \in \mathcal{T}_Y$, as required.
4. The union case is similar using

$$(\bigcup_i O_i) \cap Y = \bigcap_i (O_i \cap Y)$$

etc.